# In SQL how do you output a column that is performing a function on multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I'm learning SQL (specifically mySQL) and I've been working through the problem sets on sqlzoo.

I've gotten stumped by [one problem that is asking me to show the population of a country *as a percentage of some other country*.](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_within_SELECT_Tutorial) It's number 5. Please note the full table is not shown, but the content of the table can be inferred given the parameters: world(name, continent, area, population, gdp)

I am not sure of two things:

1. how to perform the division function between the data in two columns, and
2. how to convert this data into a percentage without creating a new variable (using 'AS').

Here is what I have tried (indented for readability):

```
SELECT name, CONCAT(ROUND(new_population))from world WHERE 
continent = 'Europe' AND
((SELECT population AS new_population from world) / 
(SELECT population FROM world where name='Germany'));
```

The error given is "Unknown column 'new_population' in 'field list'" which leads me to believe I don't understand how 'AS' works.

I realize that this doesn't really make sense because the values that come after 'AND' are new ones, and so they can't be conditions on my original select statement. But I'm not really sure how to incorporate the function otherwise.

Also, please be patient, as I am teaching this to myself, so I don't really have anyone to guide me through it. Thank you!

Comment: The first part of your `WHERE` clause does a valid comparison (does continent equal 'Europe', yes or no). But the second part does not, SQL will read that as x divided by y equals... what? anything? That will need fixing

Comment: @JoeMalpass Oh. Yes. Doh. I guess I could have written AND population AS new_population = ' [function] ' , but it seems that my attempt to perform the function is incorrect anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you want to do this logic up in your `SELECT` instead of down in the `WHERE`. `WHERE` is for filtering your result set only. `SELECT` is where you put the things you want in your result set.

```
SELECT
    name,
    population/(SELECT population FROM world WHERE name='Germany' limit 1) * 100
FROM world
WHERE continent = 'Europe'
```

Alternatively you could do this with a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT
    name,
    world.population/germany.population * 100 
FROM world CROSS JOIN (SELECT population FROM world WHERE name = 'Germany') as germany
WHERE continent = 'Europe'
```

Not too sure which one is more kosher with the tutorial you are following.

Comment: Thank you--I didn't even know that was possible! How cool. The site suggests that I need to use concat and round. So can I perform those on the "population/..." instead of adding * 100 ?

Comment: Also, why did you add a limit condition? Won't the population of Germany necessarily return 1 value?

Comment: The trick with having a subquery up in your SELECT is that it's very important that it only return a single record back, otherwise it will bork. You usually see some form of aggregation in the subquery or a `LIMIT 1` on the end with an `ORDER BY` to insure a single return.

Comment: YEa.. the `LIMIT 1` is not needed here, but it will avoid an error in real life production scenarios where some doofbrain creates a table with a bad primary key and another doofbrain sticks germany in twice. You can remove it for the tutorial though.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add a little detail on @JNevill answer

Here is the query:

```
SELECT name, CONCAT(ROUND(population/(SELECT population FROM world WHERE name = 'Germany')*100), '%') AS population
FROM world
WHERE continent = 'Europe'
```

You use here CONCAT to connect your result with % sign so you get 11%, 0%, 5%etc.. ROUND function is used to make whole number from result... In calculation you will get something like 11.15478 and they want to show result as 11%.. That's way they want to use CONCAT AND ROUND here..

GL!

Comment: Thank you! I ended up figuring out how to use CONCAT.

Comment: @APrioriRainbows well CONCAT is string function take a look [HERE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) it's not complicated at all

Comment: Oh--I meant I understand how to use it now. Thank you.

Comment: @APrioriRainbows You're welcome, I'm glad that I could help a little.. :)